# Operations Quiz

Tags: python, operators

I'm working on a operations quiz and I've got it working but there is no way of telling the user when they have entered an incorrect answer, it just goes on to the next one.

```
import random
name=(input("What is your Name?: "))
operator=(input("What operation would you like?"))
if operator=="+":
        for i in range(0,10):
            x=random.randint(0,100)
            y=random.randint(0,100)
            Ans=int(x)+int(y)
            print(x," + ",y," =")
            studentAns=int(input())
        if studentAns==Ans:
                print("Correct")
                count=count+1
                score=score+1
        else:
            print("Incorrect the correct answer is",ans)
```

Comment: Set up a while loop to check if input is in something like a list, then reprompt if necessary

Comment: I think you need an extra level of indentation on your `if/else` code. Currently, `for i in range(0,10):` will run to completion before you get to the `if studentAns==Ans:`

Comment: note that you have a typo here. You should use `ans` instead of `Ans`, especially since you're printing `,ans`.

Comment: Ah thanks it has been corrected